# Html.ActionLink(linkText, actionname, actioncontroller, routevalues, htmlAttributes) renders wrong HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following Html.ActionLink call:

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "dothis", actionName: "Index", controllerName: "SelectActioncontroller", routeValues: new { actionController = "dothisController", actionName = "dothis", actionText = "dothis" }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

But as result i get:

```
<a href="/SelectActioncontroller?actionController=dothisController&actionName=dothis&actionText=dothis">dothis</a>
```

What is wrong, by all other answers I read sofar this should result in:

```
<a href="/SelectActioncontroller/dothis?actionController=dothisController&actionName=dothis&actionText=dothis">dothis</a>
```

What do I miss?

I'm using VS2012 .net4.0 mvc4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "dothis", 
                 actionName: "Index", 
                 controllerName: "SelectActioncontroller", 
                 routeValues: new { actionController = "dothisController", actionName = "dothis", actionText = "dothis" },
                 htmlAttributes: null)
```

You are using `"Index"` action in your link, check the second parameter. Since it's the default value for an action in the default route, it isn't added to the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I actualy had a different problem before which I fixed and didn't realize that my link was already working (I was so fixed on getting a certain link). But I still wonder why do they remove something I explicitly specify?

Comment: @DoB Just to make URLs shorter and cleaner.